# Android - Build failed - Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a small project for an Android lesson and when I tried to build this error occur.

```
> Task :app:mergeReleaseResources FAILED
*UserFile*\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\23d9fa9961c0d98e61467ef24b5c00c7\transformed\recyclerview-1.2.1\res\values\values.xml:9:4: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
   > Resource compilation failed. Check logs for details.
```

I've try to Clean Projet / rebuild, I tried to rewrite or to remove the file in question, the error still occur but on some other file (for the part where I remove the file).

I've also reinstalled my Android Studio and files.

And I've also search around on StackOverflow but since I don't really get where it come from, it's hard for me to make an effective search.

You can find the code there :
https://github.com/Ulkan/OC_MaReu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your code it is running perfectly just change your **res/values/ids.xml** file.

[resource type](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources) `id` must not have a value

**ids.xml**

```
<item name="item_participant" type="id">participants</item>
```

to

```
 <item name="item_participant" type="id"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to read it. I've change it, fixe a small other issues I made and it's work now. <br/> Thanks a lot, the error message wasn't helping me at all.

Comment: Me too, it's take time to figure out the issue. But your issue solved I'm happy 

Answer (score 0):

1. Try Invalidate caches/ Restart.
2. And if you mention dependencies version in + like this 'com.google.android.material:material:1.+' remove + and put full version like this 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'.